# How can I fake a missing dependency for unit testing in python?

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-mock

I have written a python module that depends on a third-party package that isn't available on my CI testing machine, so I can't test my module remotely because I can't get past the `import dependency` statement.

If we assume there's no way I can just manually install the dependency (seems like a pain) on the CI host, what's the easiest way to fake/mock/whatever the missing third-party package so that I can test my code?

I'm only using a single class provided by the dependency, so I would happily just mock that object, if there's a way to just do that, instead of the whole module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always create a `.py` file in the same folder with the filename equivalent to the module name so it will be imported instead of the dependency.

If you want to use it only as a fallback solution when the dependency isn't available:

```
try:
    import dependency
except ImportError:
    import fakedependency as dependency
```

If your setup is more complex and the module is used in other modules as a dependency, mock it:

```
import sys, fakedependency
sys.modules['dependency'] = fakedependency
```

You can combine this with the fallback solution if you want.

Comment: the use of `sys.modules` is exactly what I needed, thanks.